# I am unable to redirect to a jsp file from servlet. It was not redirecting to the actual page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dao

How can I redirect to the other jsp pages with the help of Servlets, I mean how should I construct the if and else condition and also wants to know how can I save the data in the database?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this :

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
sc.getRequestDispatcher("/file_name.jsp").forward(request, response);
```